# Where to find locale for US in @formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/dist/locale-data/

Tags: reactjs, formatjs

I'm migrating react-intl to version 3.0, and need to polyfill locale-data for IE. Specifically I want to load a polyfill of locale data for en-US. I can only find `@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/dist/locale-data/en` locale file.

```
if (!Intl.RelativeTimeFormat) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
  require('@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/polyfill');
  // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
  require('@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/dist/locale-data/en-US');
}
```

It leads to this error :

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/dist/locale-data/en-US' in '/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/app'`

Comment: A member of formatjs replied to me that the file `@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/dist/locale-data/en` contains en-US locale. See https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/issues/203#issuecomment-531168939

Answer (score 4):

Try the below format in `"@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat": "^7.2.0",`

```
import '@formatjs/intl-pluralrules/polyfill'
import '@formatjs/intl-pluralrules/locale-data/en'
import '@formatjs/intl-pluralrules/locale-data/de'

import '@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/polyfill'
import '@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/locale-data/en'
import '@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/locale-data/de'
```

and `addLocaleData` is no removed already as per https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/upgrade-guide-3x/#migrate-to-using-native-intl-apis

Answer (score 3):

try to install :

```
npm i @formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact issue, when I checked the @formatjs directory inside node_modules/ there was no dist directory @formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/**dist/**locale-data/en so I removed it from the import and everything worked fine.